# Normality of subgroups and Sylow groups under homomorphisms...

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove or disprove: if $f:G \rightarrow H$ is a surjective group homomorphism, then

1) $f(A)$ normal implies $A$ normal.

2) $S$ is a p-Sylow subgroup of $G$ implies $f(S)$ is a Sylow-p subgroup of $H$.

I believe 1 is false since I believe we need injectivity, but I cannot think of a counterexample...

I believe 2 is true but do not know how to show it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

For (1) consider a projection $G \times G' \to G'$.  What is the image of a subgroup in $G$?

For (2) use the fact that every surjection is of the form $G \to G/H$.  Then $S$ goes to $SH/H \simeq S/(S \cap H)$.  If $|S| = p^k$ then $|S \cap H| = p^t$ for some $t \leq k$.  As $S \cap H$ is also a subgroup of $H$ we get that $p^t \ | \ |H|$ so what is the largest power of $p$ that can divide $|G/H|$?

Comment: A few questions... what is G'? I am not familiar with such notation...also, for 2, doesn't S go to S/H, not SH/H?

Comment: $G'$ is just another group, it's like saying $G_1$.

Comment: The notation $S/H$ is generally reserved for when $H \leq S$.  The image of $S$ and $SH$ are identical but $H \leq SH$.

Comment: The image of a subgroup of H is a singleton element of G' I believe under the projection

Comment: Is that normal?

Comment: Only if it is the identity...but how are we guaranteed that the function is still a homomorphism if the singleton isn't the identity?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10288/discussion-between-anthony-vasaturo-and-jim)

Comment: For question 2 I believe the answer is that k-t is the largest power...

Comment: It is the identity, so $H$ gets sent to the trivial group, which is normal, but we didn't assume anything about $H$, so just pick $G$ and $H$ so that $H$ is not normal.

Comment: Ok...Is my answer correct on the second part? Is the largest power of p that divides G/H k-t?

Comment: Yes, so if that's the order of $SH/H$ then $f(S)$ is a Sylow subgroup.